# Folding a list of tuples using Scala

Tags: scala

What's wrong with this simple scala code?

```
val l = List(("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("c", 3), ("d", 4), ("e", 5))
l.fold(0) {(acc: Int, tup: (String, Int)) => acc + tup._2}
```

> :9: error: type mismatch;
>    found   : (Int, (String, Int)) => Int
>    required: (Any, Any) => Any
>                 l.fold(0) {(acc: Int, tup: (String, Int)) => acc + tup._2}

In other functional languages (e.g., f#) this works:

```
let l = [("a", 1); ("b", 2); ("c", 3); ("d", 4)];;
List.fold(fun accm tup -> accm + (snd tup)) 0 l;;
val it : int = 10
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `fold` method assumes an associative operator and can in theory (e.g. when using parallelism) be performed in arbitrary order. The signature thus makes it clear that the accumulating type must be a super-type of the collection's element:

```
def fold[A1 >: A](z: A1)(op: (A1, A1) ⇒ A1): A1
```

The inferred super-type of `(String, Int)` and `Int` is `Any`.

This is all described in the [API documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.List).

---

What you want is a `foldLeft` or `foldRight` which do not have this restriction on the type:

```
def foldLeft[B](z: B)(f: (B, A) ⇒ B): B
```

Therefore:

```
l.foldLeft(0) { (acc, tup) => acc + tup._2 }
```

or

```
(0 /: l) { case (acc, (_, n)) => acc + n }
```